# Change col width of pdf generated by swagger maven plugin

Tags: swagger, swagger-maven-plugin

I am using swagger-maven-plugin in my jax-rs project for generating a pdf doc for all the api's using swagger annotations.

I have added the below include to get all the api's

```
include::{generated}/paths.adoc[]
```

but the generated paths.adoc for the same has following options for parameters and responses, where the ccolumn width is defined, but the defined width is causing the parameter name to overflow and go in the next line due to which the parameter is not searchable in the pdf.

```
===== Parameters

[options="header", cols=".^2a,.^3a,.^9a,.^4a"]
|===
|Type|Name|Description|Schema
...
...
...
```

```
===== Responses

[options="header", cols=".^2a,.^14a,.^4a"]
|===
|HTTP Code|Description|Schema
```

I want to change the col width the generated paths.adoc.